# Properties vs variables

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

When I have a SKScene, is it better for variables I use for scoring, life count sprites and so on, declare them as properties, or declare them as variables inside @implementation. I know about memory management of properties, but how can I release objects, when they are declared as classic variables. Do they release from memory if SKScene is released, or do I have to take care of them some special way (set them to nil or something like that). What I do care about is just memory management of them. What is better - properties, or variables.
Thank you.

Comment: Use ARC. It will handle everything for you well most of times.

Comment: There is no silver bullet. You are confusing memory management (weak vs strong) with access levels (ivars vs properties). Use ivars if you don't need to access the variable outside the scope of the class. Otherwise use properties for variables that other classes should be able to change.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what is going to use those variables.  If they are completely private then I would declare them in a private category in the implementation file:

```
@interface MySceneClass ()
{
    unsigned _score;
    NSTimeInterval _ticker;
}
```

However if other classes need to read/write them, use properties:

```
@interface MySceneClass : SKScene

@property (assign, readonly) unsigned score;
@property (assign) NSTimeInterval ticker;
```

As far as memory management is concerned they are pretty much the same when using ARC.  The compiler will deal with releasing the objects.